# Unable to type the zoom or page number

Tags: vb6, activereports

I am using Active Reports and Visual Basic 6.0 to create reports. On the reports, I used to be able to type in the zoom percentage and the page number I wanted and hit enter. Somewhere along the way something changed and now it only accepts the drop down for the percentage and the arrow buttons for the page number. Has anyone ran into this?

There isn't much online about this. I'm also aware of how out-of-date VB6 is, but it used to work.

[image: Here is the toolbar in question. I used to be able to type where it says Page Width and 1/2]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to create a separate project or use one of the samples that comes with the installer and see if those input boxes are still there?  Are you by any chance customizing the toolbar?  Maybe there is code that is also manipulating the behavior.  Can you post a screenshot if possible?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the toolbar. I used to be able to type where it says Page Width a percentage and where it says 1/2 a page number. It looks like the code for this toolbar would be in the form file (.frm), but I don't see any code that would be effecting this ability.

Comment: It's just a picture of the toolbar. Is it still not showing for you up in my original post?

Comment: I see it now. Let me talk with the support team here and find out what is going on. I will update.

Comment: Ok, if it helps, I'm using version 2.5.0.1322 of arpro2.dll and ARVIEW2.OCX. It works if I am running in debug mode in VB, but won't otherwise.